# indexPath.row is out of range (always 0)

Tags: ios, swift

I know this question has been asked multiple times already, but for some reason none of the responses I've read has solved this issue. I'm retrieving an array of MealObjects, a class that I have defined, and setting their properties to labels in a Table View with a defined limit of 5 Table View Cells. I only have one section in the Table View.

I've pasted my View Controller class below. I've marked the error in a comment. What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

class PlateViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subtitleLabel: UILabel!

    let locationHelper = LocationHelper.sharedInstance
    let userChoice = UserChoiceCollectionDataSource()
    var mealArray: [MealObject] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationHelper.setupLocation()

        locationHelper.callback = {
            self.mealArray = self.userChoice.getUserSuggestions()
        }

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 125
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        titleLabel.text = "Your Plate"
        subtitleLabel.text = "The top 5 suggestions based on the information you provided"

        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MealCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PlateTableViewCell


        let meals = mealArray[indexPath.row]

         /* FATAL ERROR: ARRAY INDEX OUT OF RANGE
         INDEXPATH.ROW = 0
         */

        print(indexPath.row)
        cell.mealTitleLabel.text = meals.mealTitle
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = meals.mealDescription
        cell.priceLabel.text = "\(meals.priceValue)"        

        return cell
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure your array is being populated when you do self.mealArray = self.userChoice.getUserSuggestions() ? You should try to print it after this line and see what you get.

Comment: 1 section and 5 rows? but your code implements 5 sections with 1 row in each section. That contradicts your description above.

Comment: `mealArray` is obviously not the size you think it is.

Comment: @dirkgroten that was one of the solutions someone else posted, I was just trying it out and I forgot to change it back before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If index 0 is out of range, it looks like your array is empty at the time the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` accesses it. You hard coded the number of rows to 5, but you should only do that if the array has at least 5 elements in it. For example, in the numberOfRowsInSection you can do

```
 return min(mealArray.count, 5)
```

I don't see where you are setting the array. Your code

```
locationHelper.callback = {

    self.mealArray = self.userChoice.getUserSuggestions()

}
```

does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

to have one section `tableView` you must do this:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mealArray.count
}
```

and after updating `mealArray` refresh `tableView`:

```
locationHelper.callback = {
    self.mealArray = self.userChoice.getUserSuggestions()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    };
}
```